# For Snowflake .NET Connector can I get column names in original (Pascal) casing?

Tags: c#, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to automatically build an Excel document from a snowflake dataset. I'm using the .NET connector in C# Core 3.1. But the column names all come back in upper case, which makes it difficult to interpret them because the original columns names are using pascal case in the database. Is it possible to set the connector up, or query the schema, in a way that preserves the original casing of the column names? (I don't have the option to rename the columns in the database)
I've tried using both the "GetSchemaTable" method and the "GetColumnSchema" method as shown below.

```
const string DATABASE_NAME = "MY_DB";
const string SCHEMA_NAME = "PUBLIC";
const string TABLE_NAME = "VW_FACT";

[Test]
public void GetColumnNamesFromTableUsingColumnSchema()
{
  // Arrange...
  var script = $"USE DATABASE {DATABASE_NAME}; SELECT * FROM {SCHEMA_NAME}.{TABLE_NAME}";
  DbDataReader actualDataset = GetDataSetFromSnowflake(script);
  // Act...
  IEnumerable<string> columnNames = GetTableNamesUsingColumnSchemaMethod(actualDataset);
  // Assert...
  Assert.AreEqual(expected: "CanTread", actual: columnNames.ElementAt(0)); 
  // actual = "CANTREAD"
}

[Test]
public void GetColumnNamesFromTableUsingTableSchema()
{
  // Arrange...
  var script = $"USE DATABASE {DATABASE_NAME}; SELECT * FROM {SCHEMA_NAME}.{TABLE_NAME}";
  DbDataReader actualDataset = GetDataSetFromSnowflake(script);
  // Act...
  IEnumerable<string> columnNames = GetTableNamesUsingTableSchemaMethod(actualDataset);
  // Assert...
  Assert.AreEqual(expected: "CanTread", actual: columnNames.ElementAt(0)); 
  // actual = "CANTREAD"
}

public DbDataReader GetDataSetFromSnowflake(string script) {
  var connection = new SnowflakeDbConnection();
  connection.ConnectionString = SNOWFLAKE_CONNECTION_STRING;
  connection.Open();
  var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
  // Convert script into series of queries... (because .NET connector can't execute scripts yet)
  var queries = script.Split(";").ToList(); 
  // Execute any queries prior to final query...
  queries.Take(queries.Count - 1).ToList().ForEach(q => { 
    cmd.CommandText = q;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  });
  // Execute final query and return dataset...
  cmd.CommandText = queries.Last();
  var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  connection.Close();
  return reader;
}

IEnumerable<string> GetTableNamesUsingTableSchemaMethod(DbDataReader reader)
{
  // Use GetSchemaTable...
  var tableSchema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
  var columnIndexForNameColumn = 2;
  for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < tableSchema.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
  {
    // Get the column name...
    yield return tableSchema.Rows[rowIndex].ItemArray[columnIndexForNameColumn].ToString();
  }
}

IEnumerable<string> GetTableNamesUsingColumnSchemaMethod(DbDataReader reader)
{
  // Use GetColumnSchema...
  var columnCollection = reader.GetColumnSchema();
  foreach (var dbCol in columnCollection)
  {
    // Get the column name...
    yield return dbCol.ColumnName;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to set the connector up, or query the schema, in a way that preserves the original casing of the column names?

Unless you [quote the literals](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html) that define your object names, they are always stored as upper-case objects and resolved in the same manner. Quoting some relevant portions from the documentation:

> **Unquoted object identifiers:**
>
> Are *case-insensitive*.
>
> When an identifier is unquoted, *it is stored and resolved in uppercase*.
>
> […] **highly recommend** choosing an identifier resolution method early in your implementation of Snowflake […]

The original casing is not retained in the stored metadata, so there is not a way to retrieve it short of [checking the raw text that formed the query](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_ddl.html).

> I don't have the option to rename the columns in the database

If case sensitive naming is important to your business logic, you will have to recreate the table with quoted literals, which will also require you to always reference them in the same form going forward:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "TableNameWithPreservedCasing" ("ColumnNameToo" string);

SELECT "ColumnNameToo" FROM "TableNameWithPreservedCasing";
```

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake documents suggested that: 
Snowflake stores these object names in uppercase unless you quote ("") the names when you create the objects.

Can you please try quoting when you create objects? 
Here is the link: https://support.snowflake.net/s/article/faq-when-i-retrieve-database-schema-table-or-column-names-why-does-snowflake-display-them-in-uppercase